# What happens when you edit an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, editing

I answered the question [Why were the Hobbit and Lord of the Ring movies released in reverse order to the books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/71178/35012) and I had the accepted answer. Later on I realized that the link was pointing to the 1978 animated LOTR movie instead of The Hobbit (1977). I fixed the link, and the next morning I had lost 25 rep on this question. It was no longer the accepted answer and I had also been downvoted.

No comments were added why it was no longer the accepted answer, and there wasn't another question which had the accepted answer.

Did editing the answer somehow automatically remove it as being the accepted answer?

Comment: You weren't downvoted, you were un-upvoted, i.e. someone who had upvoted you retracted their vote.

Answer (score 5):

There's no automatic accepting or unaccepting of answers.  The question asker manually applies the acceptance, and can remove it at any time.  Sounds like the question asker no longer finds your answer acceptable, but lacking any input from them we can't say why.